# Eclipse Remote System Explorer: create Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, project, remote-access

I have Eclipse Neon installed on Windows 10 and I'm trying to understand the Remote System Explorer (RSE) feature in order to possibly migrate my Java project to a remote Ubuntu Server 16.04 machine.

I know that you can create a project with the RSE perspective (Create Remote project on an empty remote folder for example). However, this creates a normal project, not a Java project.
What I want is to have the same features of a Java project - for example suggestion when typing `ctrl+backspace`, live error or warning notifications (underlining the respective words), etc. - in RSE.
I have both *openjdk* and *default-jdk* on my Ubuntu machine.

Is that even possible?

If this can help, this is what is shown when I try a `ctrl+backspace` on a remote file of the project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I just imported the `.classpath` and `.project` files of a previous Java project on Windows.